# ASP.NET MVC data annotations with partial class and Metadata type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have applied some validation with data annotations but somehow I am missing something in the code.
Here is my Model class in Model Folder:
[Model Class IMAGE-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79S0Y.png)

and here is my Validation Class (cs) in ViewModel Folder

[Validation Class IMAGE-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0BcK.png)

When we run the project , validation not working.

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of your partial classes for Tbl_Users are in different namespaces (InventoryLogin.Models and InventoryLogin.ViewModel).

These partial classes need to be in the same namespace for the data validation rules to be applied correctly to the class.

Comment: Thanks. can you guide me in details?

Comment: As per the answer provided by Bellash I would create a new class in the InventoryLogin.Models namespace for the empty partial class Tbl_Users you want to apply the metadata/data validation rules to.

Answer (score 0):

Create `Tbl_Users` class in a separate file and change the namespace like this

```
 namespace InventoryLogin.Models {
    [MetadataType(typeof(InventoryLogin.ViewModel.LoginValidation))]
    public partial class Tbl_Users{}
 }
```